# What is the most convenient way to make/buy step 66V DC down to 12V DC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, step-down

There is a big battery that I have which has 64-67 volts, and I need constant 12 DC volts from it.

I tried ebay, but the best buck converter that I found had limit of 55 volts. My local electronic parts store doesn't offer what I want either.

I have some basic skills in soldering, I have some resistors, diodes and MOSFETS, I know how this all work separately, buy is there a way for me to make a converter that I need? Or where to get one?

**Update:**

For instance, can I use transformer-type of this-other-pulsing-type 220 AC - DC 12 converter, but with 66V DC input?

**Update:**

Can [TPS2490DGS](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2490.pdf) help me with it? I don't understand english well, but from what I can tell from the datasheet, this thing can control two external MOSFETs providing nice custom current and voltage outputs. But how to use it? It has 10 pins...

**Update:** The max current on the output I need is 4A.

Comment: You haven't written what current you need on output.

Comment: How much access do you have to electronics lab gear? (oscilloscope, etal)

Comment: Look for 36to72VDC input converters, there are various sizes available, you may have to order online if local suppliers have no stock.  An AC input device will not always work with your DC battery supply though some will, the peak and RMS AC voltages values are also not the same so take care if you go that route.

Comment: @KalleMP thank you, that was what I was looking for! Can you write it as an answer?

Comment: Is this by chance a locomotive battery supply? Those can run up to 74VDC during charging...

Comment: uncommon size DC-DC converters are >2$/W  Common size 1$/W  , hi volume AC-DC  0.1$/W like PC ATX  ... many uncommon in stock but $$  you only specified **"convenient"**

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel my battery is a pack of 3.7-V pieces, is used in monowheels.

Comment: @AgentFire you might be wiser to match the best cells within 1% into an array so less worry about cell balancing with what 18 cells? consider matching them by tests then 4S4P array to give 4x3.65V=14.6V what are you using it for?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thank you, but the pack is assembled on a factory, I wouldn't dare ripping it apart to get my 14V somewhere there. I'm using it for lighting tuning :3

Comment: Buy a buck CC converter for LEDs and arrange LiPo array to match converter rquirements

Comment: but using 18 Lipo with 2Ah @3.6V yields 130Wh for 50W LED only gives a couple hours. A 14V lead acid battery and charger may be better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/xp-power/DTE6048S12/1470-3377-ND/5931181

[image]

- Input     18 ~ 75 Vdc
- Output    12Vdc 5A
- High Efficiency up to 92 %
- 128$us  or 2$/W